# Percentage differences of incomes

Tags: calculus, percentages

we have that $a=2b$ where $a$ is the income of $A$ and $b$ the income of $B$.

I want to write statements about the percentages that we get from that.

Since $b$ is the half of $a$ we can say that the income of $B$ is by $50\%$ less than the income of $A$, right?

What statement do we get for the other direction?

I mean : The income of $A$ is by $x\%$ more than the income of $B$.

Which number is $x$ ?

Comment: $100$ because of the word more

Comment: How do we get $100$ ? I got stuck right now.@RezhaAdrianTanuharja

Comment: $100$ percent more than $100$ percentof the income of $B$ i.e. $a=2\times b$

Comment: I haven't really understood that. I got stuck right now. So because we have all of $b$ and then we need again the whole of $b$ to get $a$  ? @RezhaAdrianTanuharja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you wanted to write is correct.

If you take income of B 100 then income of A is 200. So, income of A is 100% more than that of B.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! :-)